# Prototype: Whats the event for losing focus?

Tags: prototypejs, observers

I want to make some changes to a text field once it loses the focus but I cant figure out the event I need. This is my code:

```
Event.observe('my_text_field', '????', function(event) {
    do something here
}
```

So, what do I have to put in instead of the ???? ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the [`blur` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/blur_%28event%29):

> The blur event is fired when an element has lost focus.

And from the [DOM2 Events spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents):

> The blur event occurs when an element loses focus either via the pointing device or by tabbing navigation. This event is valid for the following elements: LABEL, INPUT, SELECT, TEXTAREA, and BUTTON.

Comment: Right, I knew that event but it didnt come to my mind that it might be the same for Prototype :D. Thanks!

Comment: @user1638055 - Prototype is just a library that abstracts away some of the standard DOM methods to make them a bit easier to work with. All event names are the same (e.g. `click`, `focus`, `blur`, `mousedown` etc).